# How to selectively update one or more sheets of same Excel workbook using python pandas retaining formulae?

Tags: python, pandas

Went through some trial-n-error using online documentation (xlrd, etc) but having no luck that accomplishes all of the below:

I have 1 xlsx workbook with several sheets and each sheet has several cells with static values and formulae. I want to read these sheets into pandas, generate new dataframes and then update the same workbook. However, I want to update only certain cells and in a way that retains the formula of the corresponding cells after the update. I want to update the same workbook and not create a new excel file.

What's the most reliable way to accomplish this? Any guidelines would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: If you want to handle cell formula, value as an excel format itself, I think xlwings is best for you. Please check https://www.xlwings.org/ It's pretty handy. Did you try?

Comment: Trying with xlwings but running into some issues. How to work interactively with equations? For e.g. say cell A2 = '"some_label" - A1'. How to set the value for 'some_label', retain this variable value and then write this as same variable name (' "some_label" - A1') to a new cell, say A3? I am probably missing something obvious here, but unable to fetch details from the docs.

Comment: Another issue/question - how to access global variable defined in the python code from excel using xlwings?

Comment: Also, I tried for e.g. something like xw.Range('C7').formula = A - 2 ; however this doesn't retain the formula in excel, only the value. I want to display the formula after the update.

Comment: I think I have this figured out, need to do more testing but this thread can be closed. Thanks!